# Symfony 3.4 not deleting the token after use

Tags: php, symfony

Hey guys I am working on a resset password feature. The user cliks on a url received by mail and provides _password1 and _password2. If they match it saves it to the database. Problem is it does not delete the token from the database ... I tryed a few things but can't seem to get it right. I got no error messages.

Just a skip on the delete. I am new to symfony and this is my first delete attempt lol

```
/**
 * @Route("/password-change")
 */
class ResettingController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @Route("/{id}/{token}", name="resetting")
     * @param ResettingController $event
     */
    public function resetting(User $user, $token, Request $request)
    {

        // Find the token in the database
        $tokendb = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle\\Entity\\PasswordToken'::class)
            ->findOneBy(array('token'=>$token));

        //Redirect if token is not valid
        if ($token == "" || !$tokendb || $token!=$tokendb->getToken())
        {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', "Lien d'accès invalide");
            return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login');
        }

        // Building the form for the view
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('_password1', PasswordType::class, array("label"=>"Entrez un nouveau mot de passe:"))
        ->add('_password2', PasswordType::class, array("label"=>"Retapez ce même mot de passe:"))
        ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // When form is submited
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {

            // Check if password 1 and 2 matches
            if( $request->request->get('form')['_password1'] && $request->request->get('form')['_password1'] == $request->request->get('form')['_password2'])
            {
                // Save the new password
                $user->setplainPassword( $request->request->get('form')['_password1'] );

                // Delete the token
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->remove($tokendb);

                // success message and redirect
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Votre mot de passe a été modifié.");
                return $this->redirectToRoute('security_login');
            }else{
                $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', "Vos deux mot de passe ne correspondent pas.");
            }
        } 

        // Sending the view
        return $this->render('Security/change-password.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'title' => "Changement de mot de passe",
            'error' => $form->getErrors()
        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Add `$em->flush();` after remove

Comment: as @FelippeDuarte it doesn't work because of no "flush" but why don't you use standard symfony's security?

Comment: I guess i got lost by reading so many tutorials that i probably ended up complicating it. But it works and I am not changing it into something else lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `$em->flush();` after `$em->remove($tokendb);` in order to perform the operation in database.

> flush()
>
> Flushes all changes to objects that have been queued up to now to the database.
>
> This effectively synchronizes the in-memory state of managed objects with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little remarks :

Use RepeatedType instead of adding two fields to the formbuilder. It did the matching check automatically